# Fragment doesn't overlay whole layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I have a bottom navigation bar and a viewpager.
In one fragment there is a recyclerview with items. On Item click it needs to open details screen of that item.

```
   addFragment(DetailsFragment(),R.id.container)
```

This is an extension.

```
fun AppCompatActivity.addFragment(fragment: Fragment, frameId: Int) {
    supportFragmentManager.inTransaction { add(frameId, fragment).addToBackStack(null) }
}
```

This is my activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <com.product.NonSwipableViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewPagerFragments"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
            android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector_bottom_navigation"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector_bottom_navigation"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation" />


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Is there any solutions to this? I tried creating another container inside of this container and it didn't work.

One solution is to use another activity. I'm just wondering if it is possible to do with a Fragment or am I doing something wrong.

Comment: is there a solution to what?

Comment: try android.R.id.content

Comment: Solution to overlaying the whole activity with another fragment, so the bottom navigation view would be hidden. Because now it is always shown.

Comment: Alban your solution worked :)

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps

Step 1: cut this line from ConstraintLayout

```
android:id="@+id/container"
```

step 2: Add these line

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>
```

your final code will look like

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <com.product.NonSwipableViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewPagerFragments"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />



    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector_bottom_navigation"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector_bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Comment: Tried it, but the same result.

Answer (score 0):

For me using `R.id.content` works